# What is the name of app for system settings on macOS

Tags: macos, applications

There was a powerful system settings app on macOS that was able to adjust launchpad icon layout and size with GUI, as well as other system settings that did not occur in preferences.

I have used it three years ago and erased my MacBook after that. I can't recall the name of that app, and google did not help.

Please inform me if anyone happens to know the name.

Comment: TinkerTool? https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerToolSys7.html

Comment: TinkerTool that's it. Thanx a lot